# No transactions are showing on my Blockchain page

Tags: blockchain.info, lost-transactions

I'm new to this but I know how to use the request button on BlockChain to receive money? The Bitcoin was sent  to the address I provided and I didn't get it. I've received money before and sent money and none of this is showing. Transactions aren't even showing on my blockchain home page. I've always used the same email address. There is always change in my Blockchain account and that not there is either. I done this over may 7times probably and never had an issue. Was I hacked? The day I requested the money I thought it was odd that no change was in there because there is always 95 cent to 50 cents in the blockchain. Because the money was sent 10 days ago. The company sent me all the information and I've never had any issue before with blockchain. Can somebody help? NO TRANSACTIONS are showing up in my whole time using blockchain and I find that odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you had money in the wallet, and it was sent out of the wallet (not by you), then it sounds like the wallet is compromised. **Do not use it anymore**. You can easily create a new one, but be mindful of security.

Receiving a payment is as simple as sharing one of your wallet's addresses with the person paying you. Once they send a transaction it will automatically show in your wallet, you don't need to do anything else for it to work.

Comment: so my 400 bucks is gone. Why am I not seeing any transactions though. Thank you

Comment: Are you using blockchain.info? What are the payment addresses your wallet is displaying? If you can post the address you expected to receive payment to someone can check it for you. DO NOT ever share your password, private keys, or seed phrase. Sharing a bitcoin receive address is safe, it only affects your privacy (someone can see how much bitcoin you've received at that address).